# Android GridLayoutManager with both column and row span

Tags: android, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I'm using `GridLayoutManager(GLM)` in my `RecyclerView`. In the `RecyclerView`, I will populate the `CardViews`, how can I set my `GLM` to render only one `CardView` in the whole screen ?

If I set the span size as 1, it renders one `CardView` per row, not whole screen.

In Simple, I want to show 1 `CardView` occupying two columns and two rows. How to achieve this ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Could you please post your recycler view item layout? I think if you simply set height of root view in item layout to "match_parent", it will do what you want.
However, if you want to divide screen 2x2 grid and want to show one item occupying all these grids, you need to us StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Answer (score -1):

Just double the height of the card for it to take the space of 2 rows. The height of each row is dependent on the single item you inflate (in your case a cardView).